# How to append the contents of a .tar file to another file

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, tar, append

I have a file named archive.tar and I want to append its contents (archive.tar is a backup file coming from a text file) to another file. I use the following command that doesn't seem to work:

```
tar -tvf archive.tar | cat archive.tar >> file
```

Comment: I edited it, I hope it's more comprehensible now

Answer (score 0):

From the `tar` man page:

> ```
> -A, --catenate, --concatenate
>        append tar files to an archive
> ```

So, assuming that your have a `big.tar` that you want to expand with the contents of `more.tar`, just use:

```
tar -A -f big.tar more.tar
```

Answer (score -1):

From the `tar` man page:

> ```
> -O, --to-stdout
>        extract files to standard output
> ```

So if you want to append the uncompressed text contents of the files in the tar to an existing text file, use:

```
tar -Oxf more.tar >> appendedfile.txt
```

`tar -tvf` only **lists** the contents of the tar, you have to extract the data somehow. If you want to append the list of files in the tar to an existing file, use

```
tar -tf more.tar >>tarfiles.txt
tar -tvf more.tar >>tarfiles.txt
```

(with `-v` you also get the file sizes/flags)

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: may I ask why is it necessary to add the x to the tar -Oxf command?

Comment: Because `-x` is what make `tar` extract the data. `-t` only lists the contents.

Comment: @user25 If thie answer solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer to help others.